# location replace too slow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm trying to make a website with a language selection menu. When a language has been chosen a cookies gets set. If you visit the website javascript should redirect you to the webpage with content in the language that has been chosen.
My problem is that the menu is visible for 1 second before the page gets changed. I want javascript to location.replace when the page loads
This is the code:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<script src="javascript\indexscript.js""></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style\indexstylesheet.css">
<script src="javascript\indexscript.js""></script>



</head>

<body onLoad="checkCookie()">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="background">
    </div>
    <div class="popup-info">
      <img class="flag" id="dutch" src="images\dutchflag.png" onclick="nl()">
      <img class="flag" id="english" src="images\englishflag.png" onclick="en()">
      <div id="textholder">
        <h1 class="lang" id="NLtext">Welke taal spreekt u?</h1>
        <h1 class="lang" id="ENtext">What language do you speak?</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/* dit maakt een div een background die geaniemeert kan worden*/
#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85098);
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
/* stijl van de div die voor de overlay moet komen*/
.popup-info {
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 450px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;    
}
/* de stijl van de vlaggen die samen veranderen*/
.flag {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;    
}



/* individueel de vlaggen op de div plaatsen*/
#dutch {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 0 0 50px;
}



#english {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 100px 50px 0 0;
}

/*stijl engelse vlag met een muis er boven*/
#english:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}


#textholder {
    left: 175px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.lang {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/*BEGIN ANIMATIES*/

/* css animatie nederlands*/

#NLtext {
    left: 50px;
    -webkit-animation-name: nl;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes nl {

    0%    {opacity: 0;}
    12,5% {opacity: 0;}
    25%   {opacity: 0;}
    37,5% {opacity: 0;}
    50%   {opacity: 1;}
    62,5% {opacity: 1;}
    75%   {opacity: 0;}
    87,5% {opacity: 0;}
    100%  {opacity: 0;}
}

/* css animatie engels*/


#ENtext {
    -webkit-animation-name: en;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes en {

    0%    {opacity: 1;}
    12,5% {opacity: 1;}
    25%   {opacity: 0;}
    37,5% {opacity: 0;}
    50%   {opacity: 0;}
    62,5% {opacity: 0;}
    75%   {opacity: 0;}
    87,5% {opacity: 0;}
    100%  {opacity: 1;}


}
/*css animatie  nederlandse vlag*/
#dutch {
     -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s;
}



#dutch:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

/*css animatie nengelse vlag*/

#english {
     -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s;
}



#english:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

/*css fade-out animatie voor overlay*/

.overlayfade {
    -webkit-animation-name: overlayfade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes overlayfade {

    0%  {opacity: 1;}
    100%{opacity: 0;}
}

/*css fade-in animatie voor het body tag*/

body {
    -webkit-animation-name: bodyfade-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes bodyfade-in {

    0%  {opacity: 0;}
    100%{opacity: 1;}
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById('notpage').style.visibility= 'hidden';

/* Deze function is gecomment om development makelijker te maken. Na afloop deze function weer gebruikbaar maken*/
function checkCookie() 
{
    var language = getCookie('language');

    if (language === 'nederlands')
   {                                 
     location.replace("nlhome.html");   
    }

    else if (language === 'engels'){
      location.replace("enhome.html");
    }

}


function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}





function continuescriptNL() 
{
    var child = document.getElementById("overlay");
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    window.setTimeout(stillgoingNL, 500);
}

function continuescriptEN() 
{
    var child = document.getElementById("overlay");
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    window.setTimeout(stillgoingEN, 500);
}


function stillgoingNL() 
{
    location.replace("nlhome.html");
}

function stillgoingEN() 
{
    location.replace("enhome.html");
}





function nl() 
{
    var lang = 'nederlands';
    setCookie("language", lang, 30);
    var OverLay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    OverLay.classList.toggle('overlayfade');
    window.setTimeout(continuescriptNL, 2000);
    function stillgoingNL() 
    {
        location.replace("nlhome.html");
    }



}
function en() 
{
    var lang = 'engels';
    setCookie("language", lang, 30);
    var OverLay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    OverLay.classList.toggle('overlayfade');
    window.setTimeout(continuescriptEN, 2000);



}
```

Comment: I realize that this question is tagged with JavaScript/CSS, but you might wish to consider switching your language redirection logic to server-side code. This way the page doesn't have to wait for all of the content to load before checking the cookies. Either that, or move your `checkCookie` call to another event other than `onload` since onload waits until everything is loaded.

Comment: Well you page is making a request to fetch a new page.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it in the `onload` event of the body. Instead, put the code inline, at the top of the page (in the head section even) so it is executed as soon as the code is parsed. That way, you're as fast as can be using JavaScript.

An even better approach is to do these checks on the server, so you can redirect right away. In that case you can either do the redirect on the server (url won't change, but you get different content), or through the client with a normal redirect, in which case the browser just needs to process the headers and fire a new request, which is still way more efficient that redirection through JavaScript. Besides, it's always a guess if JavaScript is executed at all. On the server you're more in control.

PS: Also for other code, the `onload` event may not be the best place. This event is fired after the complete document is loaded, including images and such. A better event is [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) which is fired as soon as the DOM itself is ready, but possibly before all images are loaded. This event is perfect for hooking up events to elements and other such initialization code.

But for this specific case, you don't need the DOM. You just need to redirect as soon as possible, so don't use any event at all. Just execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, server side redirection is the fastest you can get. If you do have to have the redirection in javascript, change checkCookie to an immediately executing expression

```
(function checkCookie() {
    var language = getCookie('language');
    if (language === 'nederlands') {                                 
     location.replace("nlhome.html");   
    } else if (language === 'engels') {
      location.replace("enhome.html");
    }
}());
```

Add this and getCookie function to a new js file and place it in head.

```
<head>
<script src="javascript\redirection.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
```

This way, the function checkCookie will get executed asap the page is loaded.

Also, Suggest you to add a loading spinner overlay to this HTML.

If cookie is not found, remove the spinner overlay. This also can go in the checkCookie function as an else.

This would prevent a page flash and make the redirection less bothersome.